# C# ListView index and column to string

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview that has 2 columns and a checkbox.

What i'm doing is if the checkbox is true, I want to check the text from columns 1 and 2 and make it a string.  This is what I have.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true)
                {
                    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                    string sql = "uscolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].ToString() + "' and ukcolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].ToString() + "'";
                }
            }
```

The above code doesn't work but i'm not sure which way to go with it, the .Check works as intended but the strings dont.

so in this example:

```
CheckBox|column1|Column2
True|Fruit|Apples

usColumn = "Fruit"
ulColumn = "Apples"
```

Comment: What are you using? WinFomrs? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Comment: I am wondering if you need to check the STATE here is something for example if (e.CurrentValue==CheckState.Unchecked) Would need to see the full code to see what it is your are doing

Comment: winforms not sure why populating the listview matters it's already populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for you:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < listView1.Items.Count)
{
    if (listView.Items[i].Checked)
    {
        string sql = "uscolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text + "' and ukcolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + "'";                 
        listView.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: lol duh, but yeah i still need to remove it just after i get the string :)

Comment: uk Column = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text

Comment: add that to your answer and i'll make it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Items[i].Text` rather than `ToString()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++) 
            { 
                if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true) 
                { 
                    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(i); 
                    string sql = "uscolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].Text + "' and ukcolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].Text + "'"; 
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the rows safly, you can save the item name in a array and then remove them after you go through the whole list.
This assumes that you use unique names for each one, if the Name properie is not used at all you can add a Name specificly for the deletion.

```
List<string> toDelete = new List<int>;
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)              
{                       
    if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true) 
    {  
        toDelete.Add(listView1.Items[0].Name);

        string sql = "uscolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].Text + "' and ukcolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].Text + "'";`                       
    }              
}  
foreach(string name in toDelete)
    listView1.ItemsRemoveByKey(name);
```

Another way to do it would be to remove 1 from i each time you delete.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)              
{                       
    if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true) 
    {  
        string sql = "uscolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].Text + "' and ukcolumn = '" + listView1.Items[i].Text + "'";
        listView1.Items.RemoveAt(i--);
    }              
}
```